# Saving pokemons to CSV from GitHub using python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new in python world and wondering how can I scrape data from github into CSV file, e.g.
https://gist.github.com/simsketch/1a029a8d7fca1e4c142cbfd043a68f19#file-pokemon-csv

I'm trying with this code, however it is not very successful. Definitely there should be an easier way how to do it.

Thank you in advance!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://gist.github.com/simsketch/1a029a8d7fca1e4c142cbfd043a68f19'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

pokemon_table = soup.find('table', class_= 'highlight tab-size js-file-line-container')


for pokemon in pokemon_table.find_all('tr'):
        name = [pokemon.find('td', class_= 'blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line').text]


with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not mind taking the 'Raw version' of the CSV file, the following code would work:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/simsketch/1a029a8d7fca1e4c142cbfd043a68f19/raw/bd584ee6c307cc9fab5ba38916e98a85de9c2ba7/pokemon.csv")

with open("output.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write(response.text)
```

The URL you are using does not link to the CSV's Raw version, but the following does:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/simsketch/1a029a8d7fca1e4c142cbfd043a68f19/raw/bd584ee6c307cc9fab5ba38916e98a85de9c2ba7/pokemon.csv

**Edit 1**: Just to clarify it, you can access the Raw version of that CSV file by pressing the 'Raw' button on the top-right side of the CSV file shown in the link you provided.

**Edit 2**: Also, it looks like the following URL would also work, and it is shorter and easier to 'build' based in the original URL:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/simsketch/1a029a8d7fca1e4c142cbfd043a68f19/raw/pokemon.csv

Comment: Hello Sherlock,
Everything was easier that I thought :D Regarding RAW CSV, yes I know about that, however I'm learning how to scrape, so I tried hard level :)
Big thanks! :)